# oracle UCM view rejection comments

Tags: api-doc, webcenter, oracle-ucm

in oracle webcenter content workflows , when a user reject a file and type a comment in the rejection reason , how the next user will interact with this file in the workflow can view the rejction comment ?
i can't find anyway to view this rejection comments

[image: r]

I tried to view the workflow action history table, but it didn't show any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the comment is actually stored anywhere. You would need to build a customization that stores this and then displays it to subsequent approvers.

Comment: ok thanks , is there any tutorial for that please ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a tutorial for this. Bex Huff's book "The Definitive Guide to Content Server Development" is still one of the best references.